# Spring boot + Spring mail :Standard {PORT} issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jakarta-mail

Hello i have an issue after i have added spring mail to my application.These are the app.propreties where the issue is.

```
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
server.port=${PORT}
```

this is how i am binding it in the EmailConfig class

```
@Value("${spring.mail.port}")
    private int port;
```

also this is the mail i am using

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Every time i start the app i receive this error:

```
Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'server.port' to java.lang.Integer:

    Property: server.port
    Value: ${PORT}
    Origin: class path resource [application.properties]:20:13
    Reason: failed to convert java.lang.String to java.lang.Integer

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

For some reason it seems that i cannot make requests on basic 8080 port.So i have modified the server.port to this `server.port=${PORT:9191}` and it works but i get some requests issue with some of my pages for some reason.
Thing is , i have this same configuration on another application and it works without me having to modify the port to a different number.Why is this happening? i would like to remain on standard port.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: property name is "server.port", whereas the value bound is using "spring.mail.port". which is the right property you are trying to use?

Comment: it works if i completely remove this ```server.port=${PORT}``` but what happens if i remove it? i have found the configuration on the internet

Comment: server.port has nothing to do with email sending. It is used the configure the application to run in different port other than standard 8080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remain on standard port, remove the line server.port from your application.properties (so it runs on 8080).

`server.port` - used to configure the application to run in different port other than standard port.

`spring.mail.port` - used to configure smtp server port. If your SMTP server is using standard port, you don't need to configure this property.

The other application that has the same configuration would have the PORT value set in either environment variables or system properties. It's not possible to run the application without assigning any value to PORT variable as it is a configuration parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`app.properties` have `server.port` property while in the code you try to access `${spring.mail.port}` which is empty.

Comment: if i remove this ```server.port=${PORT}``` it sends the email after a bit of data friction, but is it ok to remove it? i mean i have found it on the internet and i am not sure what it does. i use it in another application however.